# MySql Stored Procedure and Comma Separated Varchar with In Statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a stored procedure which will take a comma separated list as a value and push that into a select statement with an IN clause. I'm aware of find_in_set which works, but does have a performance overhead. I've also trialled a prepare statement but the problem remains.

My Example:

My parameter is sp1 and contains the value: 'valuex, valuey, valuez'.

```
BEGIN

    set @sql = concat('select *  from tablename WHERE assignedTo in (', sp1, ')');

    PREPARE q FROM @sql;

    execute q;

END
```

As expected, this throws an error since SQL will treat the value as column names. My question is how do I achieve: 'valuex','valuey','valuez' FROM 'valuex, valuey, valuez'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [replace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function:

```
BEGIN

    set @sql = concat("select *  from tablename WHERE assignedTo in ('", replace(sp1,",","','"), "')");

    PREPARE q FROM @sql;

    execute q;

END
```

Answer (score 2):

An option is:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_test`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_test`(`sp1` VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
    SET `sp1` := REPLACE(REPLACE(`sp1`, ', ', ','), ',', '\',\'');
    SET @`query` := CONCAT('SELECT `column0`, `column1` FROM `tablename` WHERE `assignedTo` IN (\'', `sp1`, '\');');
    PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`query`;
    EXECUTE `stmt`;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
END$$

DELIMITER ;

CALL `sp_test`('valuex, valuey, valuez');
-- SELECT `column0`, `column1` FROM `tablename` WHERE `assignedTo` IN ('valuex','valuey','valuez');
```

Comment: ahhh the simplicity annoys me slightly - I always look to over complicate - this is perfect thank you!